# Create a class with a variable number of generic type

Tags: java, generics

I would like to create a class that can handle an undefined number of generic type is that even possible with java ?

The idea behind this weird question is to create a tuple with a size fixed in his contructor where each element at position `i` is of the type at the pos `i%numberoftype`.

Comment: Answer is No. Java don't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, types in Java have a fixed number of type parameters.

The closest you could get is to have a (finite) number of related classes:

```
class Tuple1<A> { ... }

class Tuple2<A, B> { ... }

class Tuple3<A, B, C> { ... }
```

And then provide a common class with factory methods:

```
class Tuples {
  static <A> Tuple1<A> of(A a) { ... }
  static <A, B> Tuple2<A,B> of(A a, B b) { ... }
  static <A, B, C> Tuple1<A,B,C> of(A a, B b, C c) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Joachim says, Java generic types have a fixed number of type parameters.  A variable number is not supported.

AFAIK, the JLS doesn't state this explicitly, but the Java syntax for a generic class only allows declarations with a fixed number of parameters.

See [JLS 8.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) gives the grammar rules as:

```
TypeParameters    ::= '<' TypeParameterList '>'
TypeParameterList ::= TypeParameter { ',' TypeParameter }
```

(I have tweaked meta-syntax to distinguish language symbols meta-symbols.)

---

I am not aware of any main-stream programming language that supports generic / parameterized types with a variable number of type parameters.  I suspect that type-checking such a language (if it existed) would be challenging.  And, I doubt that there would be many legitimate use-cases for such a language feature.  (But perhaps that's just my lack of imagination ...)